# Finding Dynamically generated Wcf Controls by FindName()

Tags: wpf, dynamic-controls, findname

The FramworkElement.FindName() method of finding a control within a parent control seems like it should straight forward...

But I am upping the anty and it seems like the framework does not like what I'm trying to do.

First off, I do realize there are plenty of different ways of doing things and keep in mind this is the first form I am creating in WPF.

I am loading controls into a StackPanel based on the number of items in a collection.  This method is a must as the collection is determined by the number of directories within a [user entered Url].

The list builds horizontal stackpanels into a vertical stackpanel that is placed on the form during design.

So dirStackPanel is on the form.
I am inserting controlStackPanel into dirStackPanel n number of times and name each one with an identifying name: (string)("controlStackPanel" + n).

I am also filling the controlStackPanel with controls but that is a moot point considering that I can not retrieve the controlstackPanel from its parent (dirStackPanel) by name.

example:

`var getPanel = (StackPanel) this.dirStackPanel.FindName((string)("controlStackPanel" + n))`*Returns Null*

So to be clear, each control that I am inserting AT RUN TIME is being assigned a name and can easily be retrieved using a loop.  But the FindName method will not work on the first child control of the parent "StackPanel". It keeps returning a null and not the object.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8):

If you are creating the controls dynamically, you have to call [RegisterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername.aspx) first to be able to find them.

For example:

```
dirStackPanel.RegisterName(controlStackPanel.Name, controlStackPanel);
```